# UiPath - Read Range error on Orchestrator on Terminal Server

Tags: production-environment, uipath

I published my code from local to Terminal Server (Prod). I have everything set on Orchestrator like Robot, Environment, Processes and NuGet package uploaded. I started running the job and it fails after 1 minute of running.

I am getting error saying "Read range error on Orchestrator". I have valid config file on Terminal Server. I even checked Excel activity on Studio it is up to date. Don’t know where the issue is. Could anyone help me here. It would be very helpful in running my bot on Production.

Note: I am using Studio 2018.2.3 and Orchestrator 2018.4.1

On Local machine it is running fine and I am getting this issue only on Orchestrator on Terminal Server

Comment: Will you share full Exception Details?

Comment: Hey Aksh I resolved this issue. The issue I am facing earlier was related to Dependency files which were missing on Terminal server’s local drive. I copied all dependency files like Excel activities, RestSharp, csvhelper and Newtonsoft.Json from Local machine to Terminal Server.

Comment: Cool, So will  you please post this what was your resolution to this problem and mark that as an answer so will be helpful for other users in future :) @SRK

Answer (score 0):

The issue I am facing earlier was related to Dependency files which were missing on Terminal server’s local drive. I copied all dependency files like Excel activities, RestSharp, csvhelper and Newtonsoft.Json from Local machine to Terminal Server under .nuget folder.

Moreover we have to sure we have the same path for %AppData% in both Local and Terminal server.